# Error with inserting PHP form into Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I'm starting to work on this project again after leaving it for a while. I swear it worked when I left it, but I seem to be getting an error adding an entry into the database, deleting and editing works still. I think I've narrowed it down to my "create" function.

```
public function create() {
    if (!filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'name') ||
            !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'type') ||
            !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'rent_cost') ||
            !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'rental_duration') ||
            !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'level') ||
            !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'image') ||
            !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'description')) {

        return false;
    }

    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $type = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "type", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $rent_cost = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "rent_cost", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $rental_duration = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "rental_duration", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $level = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "level", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $image = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "image", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $description = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "description", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    try {
        if (!is_numeric($rent_cost OR $rental_duration OR $level)) {
            throw new DataTypeException(gettype($rent_cost OR $rental_duration OR $level), "number");
        }
        if ($name OR $type OR $rent_cost OR $rental_duration OR $level OR $image OR $description == "") {
            throw new RequiredValueException("Fatal Error: <br> Please complete all fields");
        }

        $new_rentalpokemon = new Rentalpokemon($name, $type, $rent_cost, $rental_duration, $level, $image, $description);
        $this->rentalpokemon_model->add_rentalpokemon($new_rentalpokemon);

        $view = new RentalpokemonDetail();
        $view->display($new_rentalpokemon);
    } catch (RequiredValueException $ex) {
        echo $message = $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (DataTypeException $ex) {
        echo $message = $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $message = $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

The try loop seems to give me an error no matter what, and I think it is because its not correctly reading in the information?

If I comment out either if statement in the try loop, the other causes an error when trying to add. So even when I have information typed in, it tells me that I need to complete all fields, as it says in the try loop. Any idea why it might be getting stuck? I can't seem to figure it out. Please let me know if you need more information and thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Probably those pesky gremlins came and broke your code while you were away, those ***holes break my code all the time when I'm not looking...

Comment: Thanks for the help?

Comment: what's this `gettype($rent_cost OR $rental_duration OR $level)`  certainly not the correct use of `gettype`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: I mean I will give you the boolean `OR`, that is odd usage, but ok, less precedence and all that jazz.

Comment: I've tried OR and || and neither seem to be getting the job done that I am hoping for

Comment: yea because that's where the function parameters go, not a condition.  `gettype` is not `if( .. )`  In fact your call to `gettype` should say `boolean` ... cheers!  Check it out here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f18746e94d3d492c8f5428208408d62685b72c39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your if statements are a bit off, trying something along thise lines:

```
if(!is_numeric($rent_cost) || !is_numeric($rental_duration))
```

And

```
if($name == "" || $cost == "")
```

Comment: I changed it to ($name == ""|| $type == ""|| $rent_cost == ""|| $rental_duration == ""|| $level == ""|| $image == ""|| $description == "") , but I'm still getting the same error as if I hadn't changed it

Comment: Did you also change the first if the way I mentionned in the answer?

Comment: Yes I did both, if (!is_numeric($rent_cost || $rental_duration || $level)) {
                throw new DataTypeException(gettype($rent_cost || $rental_duration || $level), "number");
            }
            if ($name == ""|| $type == ""|| $rent_cost == ""|| $rental_duration == ""|| $level == ""|| $image == ""|| $description == "") {
                throw new RequiredValueException("Fatal Error: <br> Please complete all fields");
            }

Comment: Re-read the answer, you need a separate is_numeric for each variable, you can't bundle them all together in one is_numeric

Comment: Isn't the || being used to bundle them? I'm going to try to make separate answers now, but I'm not sure how the original answer says that x.x

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot going on but the biggest issue I see is this

```
 gettype($rent_cost OR $rental_duration OR $level)
```

And this sort of thing

```
is_numeric($rent_cost OR $rental_duration OR $level)
```

These wont throw an error, but they won't do what you expect either.  What they do is evaluate that condition, which returns a boolean `true` or `false` to your function call. Therefor, this is what you get.

```
is_numeric( true );
//or (doesn't matter neither are numeric )
is_numeric( false );
```

You can see this most clearly when using `gettype`, as it tells you the type.  I took the liberty of doing it in a PHP sanbox so you can see for yourself here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f18746e94d3d492c8f5428208408d62685b72c39

Indeed, this is also a useful example of what happens.

```
echo is_numeric(1 OR 2) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52aa6e11b1923ef57d27d36dd74b0b07dedccf5c

Which outputs `false` even though both `1` and `2` are numbers.  This is because the `boolean` comparison that you are doing in the function call, does what?  It returns a `boolean` value that is not `numeric` (as I said before).  This happens first and then the result of that is then eaten up by the function `is_numeric`, and well gives it an upset tummy ... lol.

The remedy is as others posted, but not explained in so many words, is to split them up.

```
if( is_numeric( $var1 ) || is_numeric( $var1 ) )
```

etc....

Now, I don't care to take credit for the answer, but you seemed to not be understanding the reason, so I thought it prudent to walk you through it.

It's an easy mistake to make as there are no errors thrown, it's a problem of logic, not syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I wish I could mark both as correct. They both helped me figure out what I was missing.

Comment: No sweat, I don't do this for some abstract `points`  I do it because I learned a lot reading answers here in my early days, and to stay sharp with things I don't deal with on a daily basis...  Helping someone understand is a good enough reward for me.